# I have to create a webpage and load data from (eg mytestdata.com) in different div. There are multiple data in array products

Tags: html, json, ajax

Sample data in url

```
 mytestdata.com
    Products([{"id":"1","name":"ABC","details":"xyz"}
         {"id":"2","name":"DEF","details":"uvw"}])

 )
```

html code to load the data

```
<div class="itemid"></div>  
<div class="itemname"></div>
<div class="itemdetails"></div>
```

Ajax call to load the data

```
$(function () {                     
            jQuery.ajax({   
                url: "mytestdata.com",  
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
            }).success(function (result) {

            });
        });
function Products(data) {
    for (var i in data) {
            $('.itemid').html(data[i].id);
            $('.itemname').html(data[i].name);
            $('.itemdetails').html(data[i].details);
        }}
```

The issue with the code is data is loaded to html but just the last row of products in array is loaded

Output of the code

```
2
def
uvw
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you only have one node each of the destination divs. If you clone the nodes for the subsequent rows then you won't be overriding the data in the one div you have:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="itemid"></div>  
  <div class="itemname"></div>
  <div class="itemdetails"></div>
</div>

....
<script>
    function Products(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            if (i === 0) {
                $('.itemid').html(data[i].id);
                $('.itemname').html(data[i].name);
                $('.itemdetails').html(data[i].details);
            }
            else {
                var row = document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0];
                var newRow = row.cloneNode(true);
                row.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, row.parentNode.lastElementChild);

                var insertedRow = document.getElementsByClassName('row')[i];
                insertedRow.querySelector('.itemid').innerHTML = data[i].id;
                insertedRow.querySelector('.itemname').innerHTML = data[i].name;
                insertedRow.querySelector('.itemdetails').innerHTML = data[i].details;

            }
        }
    }

    $(function () {                     
        jQuery.ajax({   
            url: "mytestdata.com",  
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
        }).success(function (result) {
            Products(result)
        }).error(function (err){
            console.log("Error response: ", err);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank u for the reply. I tried your code and got the error  Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference. The json array in my example is webservice response. Is there a way I can store those data in variables and I can load in my html div using those variables. Waiting for your response.

Comment: You just have to call your `Products` function in the success callback of your ajax call and pass in the results. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: And I caught an error. It's fixed now. Forgot to reference the newly inserted row.

Comment: Thank u for new code. Now what I am getting in output is the first set of data in array and I got the error Error response: [object Object]. I think the issue is code is not incrementing value of i . It is just displaying value for i = 0. I have tried using for (var i= 0; i < Products.length; i++) instead my other for loop in my original code and getting first set of data in result. So i think issue is it is not incrementing the value of i.